# Uncaught Reference Error : JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js

Tags: javascript

When clearing the Drupal Cache it automatically enable/ checks the Compressed the cache pages options and breaks many drupal functionality.

when i inspect i found that JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js at line 5 [jQuery.noconflict() ]. i find this error on all the pages of drupal.
and also jquery.js is not loading.

I am not sure what have caused this error.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Please try to provide more information, because your question is hard to answer right now. At the very least, tell us which Drupal version you're using. Also, tell us what you changed since the last time it did work.

Comment: I am using Version 7.39. I have added a feature and enabled it after doing so when i clear the cache. Many drupal functionalities are not showing up like [drag and drop UI, Text ediotors]. As i mentioned when i inspect i find JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js at line 5 [jQuery.noconflict() ]. i find this error on all the pages of drupal. I can provide any info regarding it.

Comment: Is the site available to look at somewhere? Are there any other error messages in the Console? I've definitely had problems where my custom JS is not happy with Compressed JS and breaks things. Also on Drupal 7 -- I've never had cache clear auto-enabling the compressed options. That seems strange.

Comment: @Adrained The site is not available to look. But in console i get the error  "Uncaught Reference Error : JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js".     Yes it seems strange like cache auto-enabling the compressed options.

Comment: Try using the AdvAgg module; it usually works better than core for aggregation https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg

Comment: I have tried the module still the error seems to be there. Even i load the jquery.js file in the theme template file, It still says  JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js at line 5 [jQuery.noconflict() ]

Comment: At this point, I would start disabling modules and seeing if it fixes it. Disable, clear cache, test page, repeat. It feels like there is some conflict between modules here.